# Why JwtAuthenticator have "Bearer" in the header?

Tags: c#, jwt, restsharp, bearer-token

Hi there so i've been trying to use one of the authenticator "JwtAuthenticator" and I saw that the "Authorization" header have "Bearer" word not "JWT" is that a bug or am i doing something wrong any help please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POAHi.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnacH.png)

I'm trying to understand why does **Authorization** header have bearer word? instad of "JWT"

Comment: Can you clarify why you think it should be "JWT"?

Answer (score 2):

The **Bearer** keyword in the Authorization header of an HTTP request indicates that the request is using the Bearer authentication scheme. This scheme is used to transmit an access token, such as a JSON Web Token (**JWT**), in the HTTP header to authorize the request.

[This](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108662/why-is-bearer-required-before-the-token-in-authorization-header-in-a-http-re#:%7E:text=Bearer%20distinguishes%20the%20type%20of,re%20using%2C%20so%20it%27s%20important.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on) answer also provides enough basic information.